# bash readlline c function to insert on the command line

Tags: c, bash, command-line, readline

I have been digging in the gnu readline  library without luck for a c function like insert_cmd(char*) such as

```
insert_cmd("ls -l");
```

when executed will put the output in the prompt :

```
prompt>ls -l
```

so user can complete editing the command and run it if he so wish by pressing enter.

how to accomplish that ?

Answer (score 1):

The key bit here is 'editing the command'. You can achieve this with `libreadline` and specifically the `readline` function. `libedit` does the same thing.

You will have to achieve the 'running it if he so wish(es)' bit yourself.